# Combining three words into one?

Tags: java

I have to make a program which needs to generate three words of 10 letters, with each having 1st letter as UpperCase. Afterwards, I have to combine those three words into one word and that word again should have only its 1st letter as UpperCase.

So far I managed do to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DZ05();
}

public DZ05() {
    Random word = new Random();
     for(int i = 0; i<= 10; i++) {
        int x = word.nextInt(25)+97;
        if(i==0) {
            tekst1+= Character.toUpperCase((char) (x));
        } else {
        tekst1+= (char) (x);
        }
    }       
         for(int i = 0; i<= 10; i++) {
        int x = word.nextInt(25)+97;
        if(i==0) {
            tekst2+= Character.toUpperCase((char) (x));
        } else {
        tekst2+= (char) (x);
        }
    }
             for(int i = 0; i<= 10; i++) {
        int x = word.nextInt(25)+97;
        if(i==0) {
            tekst3+= Character.toUpperCase((char) (x));
        } else {
        tekst3+= (char) (x);
        }
    }      
    System.out.println(tekst1);
    System.out.println(tekst2);
    System.out.println(tekst3);
```

And thats where I dont know what else to do

Comment: One way would be to create a new String from the resulting three, and make all the characters in lower case except the first one. Then print this String.

Comment: It seems you're missing out on some cool String class functions ! Maybe take a look a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for helping me out. And no I didnt miss any classes I just find coding very difficult ( As I still dont understand what each command and input does... I still do java tutorials to make it a bit easier but its kinda a slow process :(
PS. I think we havent yet started to work with StringBuilder command

Answer (score 0):

You should consider breaking the problem down into multiple methods, and have your main program call those methods.

For example, you could build something like:

```
private String randomWord(int length) { ... }
private String titleCase(String word) { ... }
```

Your main program could call them and be easier to follow:

```
String fiveLetterWord = randomWord(5);
String titleCasedWord = titleCase("threeConcatenatedWords");
```

Answer (score 0):

I will make the assumption that tekst1, tekst2 and tekst3 are Strings, as this is not shown in the provided code.

Firstly, your for loops generate words with 11 not 10 letters. It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Now, there are various methods from the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class that you can use to achieve your goal. You can use  [String concatenation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) to combine the words:

```
String combinedWords = tekst1 + tekst2 + tekst3;
```

Use the String methods [toLowerCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) and [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) to get all the letters except the first in lower case:

```
String lowerCaseChars = combinedWords.toLowerCase().substring(1);
```

Use the String method [charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) to get the first letter:

```
char upperChar = combinedWords.charAt(0);
```

Finally, combining `upperChar`and `lowerCaseChars` gives you your desired result:

```
String result = upperChar + lowerCaseChars
```